# Mono compiler generated .exe runs directly from linux command line , why?

Tags: c#, linux, mono

On my Arch Linux machine I have Mono C# compiler [version 5.20.1.0] installed. I created a simple hello world program in C# today as follows:

```cs
using System;
public class Program
{
    public static int Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello world of C# !");
        Console.WriteLine();

        return 0;
    }    
}
```

I went to my bash terminal and compiled the above program as

```
$ mcs t.cs
```

This created a file name **t.exe** in the working directory. Then I entered:

```
$ ./t.exe
```

And the output was

```
Hello world of C# !
```

I was surprised to see this, as this was not previously the case. You could NOT execute a   mono produced .exe file **directly** from linux command line. To run the above produced **t.exe** executable , you had to do something like:

```
$ mono t.exe
```

To investigate further (and check the file format) produced by the mono compiler , I ran the **file** command , like so,

```
$ file t.exe
```

It produced the following output:

```
t.exe: PE32 executable (console) Intel 80386 Mono/.Net assembly, for MS Windows
```

I searched the internet, but could not figure out why this is happening. Not that I'm complaining, I'm loving it. But how can linux command line run a .net or mono executable directly like this?  What's happening ??

Comment: Hmm, did Google spit out nothing about that topic (i.e. running a mono / .NET executable in Linux)?

Comment: No -- it didn't give anything relevant. Same old stuff about how to run a  .exe file on linux with mono installed ( like I mentioned above) -- but not anything about why should a .exe file generated by mono run DIRECTLY on linux command line --- as if it were a native binary   just generated in the working directly. This is strange. I have previously built a lot of small toy .net/mono projects on Linux .... but always had to mention "mono" on bash command line before the executable -- like : 
$ mono example.exe

Comment: A quick Goolge turned out this: https://www.mono-project.com/archived/guiderunning_mono_applications/#registering-exe-as-non-native-binaries-linux-only. See the chapter about "_Registering .exe as non-native binaries (Linux only)_". Note that this is not a Mono feature, but an ability enabled by Linux' _binfmt_ subsystem. (But don't ask me about _binfmt_, i am not (yet) really a Linux user ;-) )

Comment: Oh wow thanks @elgonzo --- so its a linux kernel feature -- how could I miss it being a linux user for years now and a C# hobbyist , also for a long time. I guess , I never tried executing the .exe file directly EVER ... hence never noticed it. I think the mono installation process on Arch Linux automatically activates this binfmt thing. Will have to dig deeper.  Thanks again --- just copy paste your comment in an answer , so I can mark it correct. :)

Comment: Answer below. Come to think of it, i guess the question/answer is having a better home at http://superuser.com (as it's not really programming-related, but about system configuration). So, don't be surprised if it happens that a mod is moving your question over there.  ;-) (maybe it doesn't happen, who knows...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "direct" execution(1) of .NET .exe files in Linux is a capability enabled through Linux' [binfmt_misc](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/binfmt-misc.html) subsystem.

Quote from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binfmt_misc):

> **binfmt_misc** is a capability of the Linux kernel which allows arbitrary executable file formats to be recognized and passed to certain user space applications, such as emulators and virtual machines.

To enable "direct" execution of .NET executables, a line similar to the following needs to be present in a config file in one of the possible [binfmt.d directories](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/binfmt.d.5.html).

```
:CLR:M::MZ::/usr/bin/mono:
```

Additionally, as a final step, any .NET .exe that should be "directly" executable needs to have its execution flag set (`chmod 755 ...`).

---

(1) "Direct" execution here means that the user simply needs to type the name of the file in the shell, and *binfmt_misc* takes care of automatically executing the associated actual Linux executable/script (here in this case `mono`) while passing the name/path of the file typed into the shell.